# Don't know which classes to start to test sphinx4

Tags: eclipse, gradle, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I have done these steps

1- downloaded latest version of Sphinx4 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/5prealpha/

2-  installed **Gradle IDE Pack 3.8.x + 1.0.x** in Eclipse (Gradle plugin).

3- Imported Sphinx4 as Gradle STS project.

Now I got errors as shown in below picture

[image]

For the sake of time I have commented these errors because I don't know why these errors I am getting.

Now I want to RUN Sphinx4 but I dont know what to run and how to run. 
I have done my best with google and trying to do for days. but did not got positive results.

If any one can help me to solve the issue and guide me how to run sphinx4 as gradle that would be great. As you can see there are 4 projects sphinx so Which one to run.

That might be silly to ask, "If I run successfully what would be output"

PS: I am new to Gradle and Sphinx4
and also have taken look at [this link](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4)

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial [says](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4/#demos)

A number of sample demos are included in sphinx4 sources in order to give you understanding how to run Sphinx4. You can run them from sphinx4-samples jar:

- [Transcriber](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-samples/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/TranscriberDemo.java) - demonstrates how to transcribe a file
- Dialog - demonstrates how to lead dialog with a user
- SpeakerID - speaker identification
- Aligner - demonstration of audio to transcription timestamping

You just need to read it carefully.

Comment: Nikolay can you have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691518/make-sphinx4-recognize-all-the-numbers-using-custom-gram-file ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find **tutorials**: -> [here](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Speech-Recognizer-Tutorial--Calculator) <-

Although i am adding the jars to the classpath differently it will work for you.

---

**Simple example code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Port;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;

public class Main {

    // Logger
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    // Variables
    private String result;

    // Threads
    Thread  speechThread;
    Thread  resourcesThread;

    // LiveRecognizer
    private LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Main() {

        // Loading Message
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Loading..\n");

        // Configuration
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        // Load model from the jar
        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");

        // if you want to use LanguageModelPath disable the 3 lines after which
        // are setting a custom grammar->

        // configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin")

        // Grammar
        configuration.setGrammarPath("resource:/grammars");
        configuration.setGrammarName("grammar");
        configuration.setUseGrammar(true);

        try {
            recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // Start recognition process pruning previously cached data.
        recognizer.startRecognition(true);

        // Start the Thread
        startSpeechThread();
        startResourcesThread();
    }

    /**
     * Starting the main Thread of speech recognition
     */
    protected void startSpeechThread() {

        // alive?
        if (speechThread != null && speechThread.isAlive())
            return;

        // initialise
        speechThread = new Thread(() -> {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "You can start to speak...\n");
            try {
                while (true) {
                    /*
                     * This method will return when the end of speech is
                     * reached. Note that the end pointer will determine the end
                     * of speech.
                     */
                    SpeechResult speechResult = recognizer.getResult();
                    if (speechResult != null) {

                        result = speechResult.getHypothesis();
                        System.out.println("You said: [" + result + "]\n");
                        // logger.log(Level.INFO, "You said: " + result + "\n")

                    } else
                        logger.log(Level.INFO, "I can't understand what you said.\n");

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
            }

            logger.log(Level.INFO, "SpeechThread has exited...");
        });

        // Start
        speechThread.start();

    }

    /**
     * Starting a Thread that checks if the resources needed to the
     * SpeechRecognition library are available
     */
    protected void startResourcesThread() {

        // alive?
        if (resourcesThread != null && resourcesThread.isAlive())
            return;

        resourcesThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {

                // Detect if the microphone is available
                while (true) {
                    if (AudioSystem.isLineSupported(Port.Info.MICROPHONE)) {
                        // logger.log(Level.INFO, "Microphone is available.\n")
                    } else {
                        // logger.log(Level.INFO, "Microphone is not
                        // available.\n")

                    }

                    // Sleep some period
                    Thread.sleep(350);
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
                resourcesThread.interrupt();
            }
        });

        // Start
        resourcesThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Takes a decision based on the given result
     */
    public void makeDesicion(String result) {
        //implemented in the part 2
    }

    /**
     * Java Main Application Method
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // // Be sure that the user can't start this application by not giving
        // the
        // // correct entry string
        // if (args.length == 1 && "SPEECH".equalsIgnoreCase(args[0]))
        new Main();
        // else
        // Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Give me
        // the correct entry string..");

    }

}
```

---

**Grammar File:**

```
#JSGF V1.0;

/**
 * JSGF Grammar 
 */

grammar grammar;

public <numbers> = (one | two | three| four| five | six | seven | eight | nine | ten);
public <action>  = (plus | minus | multiply | division);
public <final> = (show result);
```

Comment: it is help full. I will explore it and will let you know

Comment: @Adnan Ali It is a full working example of LiveSpeechRecognition. It is used in real application code ;)

Comment: @AdnanAli did you explore it ? tell us when you arrive in your app

Answer (score 0):

These errors occur because your encoding isn't set right.

In Eclipse go to `Edit -> Set Encoding -> UTF-8`

Comment: If everything went well, it should have changed those weird signs to: https://gyazo.com/5d8494538630eeb60d94646e5acb0506 Also make sure you open the file first, then go to encoding. The settings change the encoding for the opened file only! With my project USEnglishTokenizer also had this problem: https://gyazo.com/0f99cab48e7fde07a5b5fc1ea92315c7 If you still have an error, there should be something else that is wrong