# Make Sphinx4 Recognize all the numbers using custom .gram file

Tags: java, speech-recognition, sphinx4

**Description**

A speech recognizer calculator in Java Using [Sphinx4 library](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4/)  exists.

The full code on github: [here](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Speech-Recognizer-Tutorial--Calculator)

---

The gram file  i am using is the below([on github](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Speech-Recognizer-Tutorial--Calculator/blob/master/Part2/resources/grammars/grammar.gram)):

```
#JSGF V1.0;

/**
 * JSGF Grammar 
 */

grammar grammar;

public <syntax>  = (one | two | three| four| five | six | seven | eight | nine | ten | eleven | twelve | thirteen | fourteen | fifteen | sixteen | seventeen | eighteen | nineteen | twenty) 
                                                          (plus | minus | multiply | division)                          
                   (one | two | three| four| five | six | seven | eight | nine | ten | eleven | twelve | thirteen | fourteen | fifteen | sixteen | seventeen | eighteen | nineteen | twenty);
```

---

**The problem:**

`I want the program to be able to recognize numbers from 0 to 1 million  in English Language` .

In the current state as you can see it can recognize  the numbers `(one | two | three| four| five | six | seven | eight | nine | ten | eleven | twelve | thirteen | fourteen | fifteen | sixteen | seventeen | eighteen | nineteen | twenty)`, as i have written them manually into the `gram file` .

I mean i have to write them all manually into the `gram file`(i can create a program to produce that file) but again it is seems impossible(some pattern may exist),the file will be too much gigabytes.

---

**Finally:**

Is there any smart solution?Thanks for the effort :)

---

The new grammar after `Nikolay` Solution is:

```
public <number> = (one | two | three | four | five | six | seven | nine | ten
                   | eleven | twelve | thirteen | fourteen | fifteen | sixteen | seventeen | eighteen | nineteen | twenty 
                   | thirty | forty | fifty | sixty  | seventy | eighty | ninety | hundred | thousand | million | billion)+;                   
public <syntax> = <number>{1} (plus | minus | multiply | division){1} <number>{1};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smartest solution is to recognize a text string first. Grammar should not be complex, it should just list the words used in numbers:

```
 grammar number;

 public <number> = (one | two | three | four | five | six | seven |
 nine | ten | eleven | twelve | thirteen | fourteen | fifteen | 
 sixteen | seventeen | eighteen | nineteen | twenty | thirty | forty | 
 fifty | sixty  | seventy | eighty | ninety | hundred | thousand |
 million | and )*;
```

Once text is recognized, convert it to numbers. You can check  [How to convert words to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062022/how-to-convert-words-to-a-number) for details.

Comment: Nikolay i have done the second part for converting words to number or number to words . The problem i have is that the grammar file only recognizes the numbers i have written.... , `(one | two | three| four| five | six | seven | eight | nine | ten | eleven | twelve | thirteen | fourteen | fifteen | sixteen | seventeen | eighteen | nineteen | twenty)` , i want it to recognize every number ...Since i can't use a `language model` with a `grammar` i have stacked here ... Is there any special word `<number>` that i can use into the `grammar file` ?

Comment: There are no special words.

Comment: Is there a way then to recognize all the numbers using a grammar(As string format)? :) Only that i want , nothing more , i can do the other stuff.

Comment: Thanks! . Your pattern works although `spinhx4` has very big problems, simply it doesn't recognize for example `one thousand twenty four` or things like that... I have edited the question containing the grammar i use after your answer. If you want have a look to say me if i am doing something wrong or just simply `sphinx4-5` needs more improvement or training.